# how to read int value from dataset? in C#

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

if I have a function that return DataSet , that have 1 row with int value .

how can i read that int value ?

Comment: [C# ADO.NET OleDbCommand - ExecuteScalar](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-oledbcommand-executescalar.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why to use dataset for single static value. Use ExecuteScalar function if you are using sql reader

Example:

```
function GetIntValue()
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["con"]);

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees",con);
    int numberOfEmployees = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
    Response.Write("Here are the " + numberOfEmployees.ToString() + " employees: <br><br>");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees",con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(dr.Read()) {
        Response.Write(dr["LastName"] + "<br>");
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: sorry , i didnt understand the answer .

i did  a function that return me 1 row with 1 value in there and i want do someing like

textbox1.text = function().getdata 

how can i do it ?

Comment: please refer this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Comment: @user2120874 Instead of reading the function into a DataSet, use  ExecuteScalar() as referenced above to read the function result directly into a variable.